# How import data from a text file into 2D list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I was trying to make a random generator for DND Classes and Subclasses.  I tried making a text file that looks like this:

```
Barbarian
  Ancestral Guardian
  Battle Rager
  Beast
  Berserker
  Storm Herald
  Totem Warrior
  Wild Magic
  Zealot
Bard
  Creation
  Eloquence
  Glamour
  Lore
  Spirits
  Swords
  Valor
  Whispers
```

Normally I would code in the data into a list like this:

```
backgrounds = {}
with open("./Data/backgrounds.txt") as text:
  backgrounds = text.readlines()
text.close()
```

Is there anyway for it to read this data as say Barbarian Battle rager would be position (0,1) and bard glamour would be (1, 2)?
Or is there a better way to format the data so it can be put into this 2D list? Thank you!

Comment: You can use JSON or YAML format to store this kind of data and directly import them into python nested structure.

Answer (score 1):

First: you don't want a 2D list; you want a simple dictionary of strings to string lists.

Also, as suggested in the comments if your format is flexible, use JSON or XML rather than a flat text file. If your format is not flexible, the following will do the trick:

```
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Dict, List

classes: Dict[str, List[str]] = {}

with open('./Data/classes.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(' '):
            current_classes.append(line.strip())
        else:
            current_classes = classes.setdefault(line.rstrip(), [])


pprint(skills)
```

Comment: It shows a more legible dictionary representation. It's only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: thanx, you should most probably add an embebded  link

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JSON`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)  format to store this kind of data and directly import them into python list with the [json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json). I have taken the liberty to adjust your text file to a json file

**backgrounds.json:**

```
{
    "Barbarian":["Ancestral Guardian","Battle Rager","Beast","Berserker","Storm Herald","Totem Warrior","Wild Magic",""],
    "Bard":["Creation","Eloquence","Glamour","Lore","Spirits","Swords","Valor"," Whispers"]
}
```

**The python code:**

```
import json
with open('backgrounds.json','r') as file:
    backgrounds = json.load(file)

print(backgrounds)
```